# Copy only the selected values form one table to another one with where clause in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

I have a table with duplicated rows (table: electricity_meters). And there is another table (table: power_consumptions) that tells me which row of the first table to keep.

Trying delete the duplicated rows in SQLite with CTE, but not working.

Here is what I am trying, with DB Browser for SQLite:

```
with CTE_table AS
(
select *, row_number() over (PARTITION by serial_number ORDER by consumed_value DESC) as row_num
from electricity_meters
left JOIN power_consumtions on electricity_meters.adressId=power_consumptions.adressId
)
delete from CTE_table
WHERE row_num > 1
```

And the result:

```
Execution finished with errors.
Result: no such column: row_num
```

serial_number is in the first table (electricity_meters), and the consumed_value is in the second table (power_consumtions).

Any suggestions or help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a sqlite DB with a TABLE "TxData" and these two columns NxData and txSearchMonth both are integer types
try adding a condition statement WHERE row_num = your value

```
UPDATE TxData SET NxData = txSearchMonth
```

Comment: I don't fully understand this. :(

Comment: @ImrePocsai How many Tables are you working with ? If all the data you want to delete is in one column move it to another column What you do with the data in the new column is not clear from your question So what do you want to do with the data you want to delete If you just want to delete it if it is a duplicate then write a DELETE statement with conditions

Comment: I want to delete the complete rows. All rows are duplicated, and the second table tells wich row is needed.